# Pass function to click event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just wondering what I need to do to pass the `clickAssistanceToggle` function to my jQuery click event, I have taken a look at some of the answers on here and can't find a simple solution to this.

So far I have this code:

```
  function clickAssistanceToggle() {
    $('.car-hub-header-help, #assistance-overlay, .assistance-close-btn').click(function(){
      $('#new-car-hub, #new-car-offer').toggleClass('assistance-active');
      $('#pulman-assistance').toggleClass('pulman-assistance-active').css("top", fixedPositionCalculator);
      $('#assistance-overlay').toggleClass('assistance-overlay-active');
      $('#new-car').toggleClass('assistance-active-body');
      $('#new-car-offer-cta').toggleClass('assistance-active-cta');
    });
  };
  $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(function(){
    clickAssistanceToggle();
  });
```

As you can see the function wont run like this because it hasn't been passed as a parameter, I have tried passing the function like so:

```
  $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(function(clickAssistanceToggle){
    clickAssistanceToggle();
  });
```

However this does not seem to work, any idea how I can pass that function to the click event? Thanks

Comment: Apparently, your clickAssistanceToggle function is itself assigning a click handler to a bunch of other elements. Can you explain the intended purpose?

Comment: Are you sure your code is not working? The code in the first block has nothing blatantly wrong, the only problem is that it has no immediate visible effect. As it is, when the user clicks on `.new-car-general-enquiry-btn` the attached function is called and it attaches another click handler to other elements. The toggleClass methods are only executed when the user clicks on one of these elements `.car-hub-header-help, #assistance-overlay, .assistance-close-btn`. This said, the second block code of course is wrong.

Comment: Thanks your totally right, I guess I got a little confused and thought it was because the function wasn't being called. I didn't recognise that I was calling a function that contained a click event within a click function.

Comment: Ok then, now i'm confused... why did you mark as correct an answer that was pointing you in a wrong direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call like this,

```
 $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(clickAssistanceToggle);
```

Or

```
 $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(function(){
    clickAssistanceToggle();
  });
```

Also there is a chance that, .new-car-general-enquiry-btn element is not being rendered at the time of binding the event. If so you need to wrap the code inside dom ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(function() {
    clickAssistanceToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(function(clickAssistanceToggle){
    clickAssistanceToggle();
  });
```

You need to use

```
 $('.new-car-general-enquiry-btn').click(clickAssistanceToggle);
```

Basically you need to pass the function to be executed when a click is performed on a `.new-car-general-enquiry-btn` element.